# Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, response.redirect

I am getting the error:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

I have redirected to a new page in repeater's itemcommand event. The error occurs at the line:

```
string url = "~/Galleries/AlbumImageList.aspx?UId=" + this.UserId.ToString() + "&AlbumId=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString();
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Can anybody please help me? Is anything wrong there?
The `_COMPlusExceptionCode` is -`532459699`.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Make second argument of `Response` **false** as shown below.

```
Response.Redirect(url,false);
```

Comment: tried adding false but still not work for me

Answer (score 163):

```
Request.Redirect(url,false);
```

`false` indicates whether execution of current page should terminate.

Comment: Is there anything like Request.Redirect(url,false)?

Comment: there is no redirect property of request

Comment: @karan which version you are using as well request will be like that "Request"

Answer (score 69):

### Resolution

> To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:
>
> - For [**Response.End**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524629%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), call the [**HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.applicationinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>     method instead of **Response.End** to bypass the code execution to the
>     **Application_EndRequest** event.
> - For [**Response.Redirect**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), use an overload, **Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse)** that passes **false** for the **endResponse** parameter to suppress the internal call to **Response.End**. For example: ***`Response.Redirect
>     ("nextpage.aspx", false);`*** If you use this workaround, the code
>     that follows Response.Redirect is executed.
> - For [**Server.Transfer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), use the [**Server.Execute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method instead.

### Symptoms

> If you use the Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer
>   method, a ThreadAbortException exception occurs. You can use a
>   try-catch statement to catch this exception.

### Cause

> The Response.End method ends the page execution and shifts the
>   execution to the Application_EndRequest event in the application's
>   event pipeline. The line of code that follows Response.End is not
>   executed.
>
> This problem occurs in the Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer
>   methods because both methods call Response.End internally.

### Status

> This behavior is by design.

### Properties

> Article ID: 312629 - Last Review: August 30, 2012 - Revision: 4.0
>
> **Applies to**
>
> - Microsoft ASP.NET 4.5
> - Microsoft ASP.NET 4
> - Microsoft ASP.NET 3.5
> - Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0
> - Microsoft ASP.NET 1.1
> - Microsoft ASP.NET 1.0
>
> **Keywords:** kbexcepthandling kbprb KB312629

**Source:** [PRB: ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us)

Answer (score 14):

In a bug I was investigating there was a Response.Redirect() and it was executing in an **unexpected location** (*read: inappropriate location - inside a member property getter method*).

If you're debugging a problem and experience the "*Unable to evaluate expression...*" exception:

1. Perform a search for `Response.Redirect()` and either make the second parameter *endResponse* = **false**, or
2. Temporarily disable the *redirect call*.

This was frustrating as it would appear to execute the *Redirect call* before the "step through" on the debugger had reached that location.

Answer (score 13):

Please check this link for the reason behind this issue and solution for the error:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/

Microsoft Support Article:

PRB: ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer Print Print Email Email

> To work around this problem, use one of the following methods: For
> Response.End, call the
> HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead
> of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the
> Application_EndRequest event.
>
> For Response.Redirect, use an overload,
> Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse)
> that passes false for
> the endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to
> Response.End.
>
> For example:   Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx",
> false);
>
> If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed. For Server.Transfer, use the
> Server.Execute method instead.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem too, and it was tricky. For me, it was because I'm using Ext.Js javascript library. If you are doing a response.redirect in server-side code that you accessed *in an Ajax call*, there are problems. Ext.js has a workaround with their Ext.Redirect method.

Answer (score 3):

Also You Can Use [`Server.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

use this code solve the problem:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "Uploadfile\\" + fileName;
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
byte[] bt = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(bt, 0, (int)fs.Length);
fs.Close();
Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName;+ "\"");
try
{
    if (bt != null)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bt, true);
        stream1.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bt);
        //Response.OutputStream.Write(bt, 0, (int)stream1.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        // Response.End();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: A little more explanation of what this code does would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Just encase someone else ran into the issues I did  I was using Response.End()  an async trigger button

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_login" />
```

in an update panel. I switched to regular post back not the best but it worked.

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_login" />.
```

Since I was only redirecting on the page this was a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Update Panel and link button to download excel is inside the panel than add postback trigger

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkTemplate" />
```

and in Code behind inside click event

```
string ServerPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + "Template.xlsx";
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath(ServerPath));

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
 HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, works for me always.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false);
```

Here, Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) simply redirects to the url of the current context, while the second parameter "false" indicates to either endResponse or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your answer, why does it work how does it solve the problem, so others can understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be a result when you have a razor page in mvc with a model that has some validation rules. When you post from a form and you forget to display validation errors on some field, then this message might come up. Speculation: this could be if the method you are posting to is different and used by other sources or resides in a different place than the method serving the original request.

So because it's different, it can't return to the original page to display or handle the errors because the excecution and model state is not the same (something like that).

It can be slightly difficult to discover, but easy mistake to do. Make sure your recieving method actually validates all possible ways to post to it.

for instance, even if you have serverside validation that actually makes it impossible to write in the form a string that is bigger than the max allowed by your validation, there could be other ways and sources that post to the recieving method.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue on **SharePoint** while using the SPUtility.Redirect

The solution was to change the second parameter from SPRedirectFlags.Default to SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse

```
SPUtility.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse, HttpContext.Current);
```