# Unable to evaluate expression... on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, exception, error-handling

Related to this question:  [Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is)

I am currently seeing this in my exception:

> {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Here's the offending code.  The exception is thrown on response.End();

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add(table); 
// Table is a well-formatted DataTable formed from data stored in a Session variable

HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.Charset = "";


response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"ExcelFile.xls\"");


using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid { DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0] };

    dataGrid.DataBind();
    dataGrid.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);

    response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    response.End();
}
```

This code is being used in an "export to excel" button on a web page.  This is copied directly from another page that uses the same functionality that works correctly.

Any ideas on how to debug this issue?  How can I get to a point where I can see the exception?  Also, how does the related question apply here?  The top answer and selected answers are incredibly vague.

Please note that the data in `table` is stored in Session state.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try moving `Response.End()` outside of the `using` block.

Comment: @mellamokb No dice.  : (

Comment: Why are you calling `Response.End()` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine. When you do Response.End() you get a ThreadAbortException:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/

Some people consider Response.End() too drastic though:

[Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful)

I would suggest handling this specific exception (since you know you are going to get it), and moving the reponse.End() (like mellamokb suggested):

```
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        try
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            dataSet.Tables.Add(table);

            response.Clear();
            response.Charset = "";

            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"ExcelFile.xls\"");

            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            using (HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid { DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0] };

                dataGrid.DataBind();
                dataGrid.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);

                response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());

            }
            response.End();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {
            //Log some trace info here
        }
```

Comment: In place of Response.End() you have to use HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() 
 
and in place of Response.Redirect, use the Response.Redirect ("Error.aspx", false);
  
and in place of Server.Transfer, use the Server.Execute method

Answer (score 4):

It can be solved without getting an exception.

Instead of the

`Response.End()`

use the

`Response.Flush()`

function which does not stop the execution of the page.

I've also had some problems when I've tried to download an *.xlsx* file using the `Reponse` of the page: after opening the excel file I've got the following error text:

> Excel found unreadble content in myFilename.xlsx. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this book, click Yes.

Solved this with adding `Response.SuppressContent = true;` after the `Response.Flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() instead of Response.End()