# Exception generated by Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am letting user download file  using following code. It works fine but also generates error and source for error is `Response.End();`

**Error Message** :Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.`

Below is my code. How can i handle this error and is this error not freeing my resources which can result in unwanted memory use.

I use this for asp.net webform application.

```
    try
    {
        string fileName = Request["file_ID"];
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/"+fileName);


        //string = Server.MapPath(strRequest); 
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/"+file.Extension;
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();

            // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
           // Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('aa')", true);

        }
        else
        {
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "myWindow.close();", true);
        }
    }


    catch (Exception rt)
    {
         Response.Write(rt.Message);
    }
}
```

I was looking at this solution but i am not sure how i can implement it in my code.

[Unable to evaluate expression... on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756359/unable-to-evaluate-expression-on-web-page)

UPDATE:

I actually want user to download file and close same with using code behind script which are commented in code right now.

So i am not sure how to better optimize this code to handle the exception generated by respond.end statement.

I tried to use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "myWindow.close();", true);` but it doesn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The other answer seems to be saying you can either not use Response.End as it is unnecessary, or add a catch for ThreadAbortException where you have your current catch

The question links to  [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful) that suggests adding the following:

```
// Sends the response buffer
Response.Flush()

// Prevents any other content from being sent to the browser
Response.SuppressContent = TrueResponse.SuppressContent = True
```

Comment: I think better approach use  advices suggested by users and also use .ashx file for this then i dont need to work about closing window. for any exception error i will redirect them to error page.

Answer (score 1):

use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest`

OR TRY SOMETHING LIKE

```
Response.OutputStream.Flush()
Response.OutputStream.Close()
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

READ [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful)

Comment: I think better approach use  advices suggested by users and also use .ashx file for this then i dont need to work about closing window. for any exception error i will redirect them to error page.