# "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the stack" while export the grid into excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

Getting an error while exporting the selected rows of grid into excel.
error: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the stack.

Actually I want to export the selected rows from the grid to excel, so the user can easily download the selected records
please refer the code for Export to excel Onclick method.

```
protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                bool isSelected = false;
                foreach (GridViewRow i in gvDistrictSchoolReport.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)i.FindControl("Chkbox");
                    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
                    {
                        isSelected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isSelected)
                {
                    GridView gvExport = gvDistrictSchoolReport;
                    // this below line for not export checkbox to excel file
                    gvExport.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    foreach (GridViewRow i in gvDistrictSchoolReport.Rows)
                    {
                        gvExport.Rows[i.RowIndex].Visible = false;
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)i.FindControl("Chkbox");
                        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
                        {
                            gvExport.Rows[i.RowIndex].Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportGridData.xls");
                        Response.Charset = "";
                        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                        HtmlTextWriter htW = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                        gvExport.RenderControl(htW);
                        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();

                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: There're some questions and answers dealing with this exception. Some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756359/unable-to-evaluate-expression-on-web-page.  You should also take a look here: [MS KB for ThreadAbortException](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response-end-response-redir)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using update panel then use PostBack Triggers like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvDistrictSchoolReport" /> -- for grid
             <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button6" />  -- for export to excel button
    </Triggers>
```

before the grid. Hope this will work