# Got error after logout from master page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, response.redirect

I created the sample for role authentication in asp.net 2005. I created the login panel on my default.aspx page and after login it works fine. Iused the code as below for login

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUName.Text, true, urlpath);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUName.Text, true);
Response.Redirect(urlpath, false);
```

I used all required page links in a single master page that is shown after login.
I used the code in master page for "logout" like below on clicks of link button

```
 try
 {
      Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx" );
 }
 catch (Exception ee)
 { 
      return;
 }
```

Now when I logout from master page I got an error like this

```
unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or native frame is on top of call stack
```

I have goggled but not got the solution. I am unable to find-out the reason behind this.
Please provide the proper solution.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is

Comment: Remove the try/catch on you redirect -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us
```

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods: 
•For Response.End, call the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the Application_EndRequest event.

•For Response.Redirect, use an overload, Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse) that passes false for the endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End. For example: 
  Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);

If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed.
•For Server.Transfer, use the Server.Execute method instead.