# stop exceptions bubbling up in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is like this

```
 private void GetShippingInstruction()
{
    try
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);
        ShowResult(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //custom logic        
    }

}

 private void ShowResult(string json )
{
    try
    {
        Response.Write(json);
        Response.End();
    }
    catch 
    { 
       return;
        // do nothing for now
    }

}
```

If any error occurs inside ShowResult function I want ignore that Error and go on. I have tried some thing like adding `return` in the catch block. But its not helping me, after executing the catch block of `ShorResult()` it directly goes to the Catch block of `GetShippingInstruction` , which I do not want. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Sample Code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jbse21

And the error I get: `{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}`

Comment: Your example is wrong because the catch with a return WILL handle the exception and it will thus NOT bubble up.

Comment: @TomTom  Well I have pasted the same code , and for some reason, this is what Happening to me.

Comment: Why don't you handle exception in `ShowResult` method too. Do not let it throw the exception.

`catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Handle ShowResult exception
    }`

Comment: Can you provide code that can reproduce the problem you describe. Here is a simplified version of your code and it does not behave as you describe https://dotnetfiddle.net/fDNdMw.

Comment: The `return;` is useless and might interfere. I would remove that line just to be sure.

Comment: I think TomTom is right so do make sure this isn't a diagnostic or debugging problem.

Comment: @BenRobinson I have added my complete code here
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jbse21

Comment: ...which doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: It's entirely possible that, as stated in an answer below, the exception is not actually in the ShowResult method, but in the statement where you serialize your object.

Comment: @J.Steen No I have now have only the code that I put in fiddle. and the exception I get is
{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: In that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is And please don't look at *just* the accepted answer. Read all of the helpful answers to see if any of them will help you.

Comment: @J.Steen Yap. I guess this is what My problem is. But still no Idea, Why this event bubbling happens;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that the exception is thrown in the first line of GetShippingInstruction?

> string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);

If so, it's the GetShippingInstruction catch block that will execute.

Answer (score 1):

when you call Response.Write - you open your response .. you might need to close it when error occurs while writing.. please try the following:

```
private void ShowResult(string json)
{
    try
    {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) return; // no need to get an exception for that

         Response.Write(json);

    }
    catch 
    { 

    }
    finally
    {
        Response.End();
    }

}
```