# Response.Redirect throws Error

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I'm trying to implement Response.Redirect within an ASHX file.  Initially I was having the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is), but now I'm getting

> Expression has been evaluated and has no value

on the line with "context.Response.Redirect(redirectPage,false);"

The following is my code (abbreviated).

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    redirectPage = configuration.Value.SingleLogoutServiceUrl;

    if (redirectPage != string.Empty) {
        context.Response.Redirect(redirectPage,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The message, _Expression has been evaluated and has no value_, is coming from the debugger, which has evaluated the line and since the method is `void`, the expression has no value.

Comment: @MarkCidade So therefore this isn't really an error, and is expected behavior?

Comment: Shouldn't the method redirect the HTTP response regardless of the return type?

Comment: @mason Correct. It isn't an error. You are looking at a debugger message, not an application message.

Comment: @MarkCidade There we go. If I were you, I'd turn that into an answer.

Comment: Yes - sorry I was geting this in the debugger.  But is there no way to get the page to redirect?  Would I have to change the return type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was that I was redirecting from a localhost environment to a site on the Internet and the site was rejecting the transfer.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The message, *Expression has been evaluated and has no value*, is coming from the debugger, which has evaluated the line and since the method is `void`, the expression has no value.

It isn't an error. You are looking at a debugger message, not an application message.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me how I'd do the redirect off of the handler?  It's still not redirecting and I'm not sure what I need to do to make this happen.

Comment: So long as `redirectPage==null || redirectPage.Length > 0` and nothing is wrong, the code should work.