# Response,End() giving error

Tags: c#, .net

Below is my code. In `response.end()` this error occurs: `"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or the native frame is on top of the call stake."`

```
 try
            {
                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.Buffer = true;
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".csv");
                context.Response.Charset = "";
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/text";


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int k = 0; k < dtCsv.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    //add separator
                    sb.Append(dtCsv.Columns[k].ColumnName + ',');
                }
                //append new line
                sb.Append("\r\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < dtCsv.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < dtCsv.Columns.Count; k++)
                    {
                        //add separator
                        sb.Append(dtCsv.Rows[i][k].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
                    }
                    //append new line
                    sb.Append("\r\n");
                }
                context.Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: where do you call this from?

Comment: Consider [not using Response.End](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful).  It's really a hangover from Classic ASP and isn't (usually) usefully called in .Net

Comment: i call it from the Page.aspx.cs file.

Comment: Have you tried some recommendations from this link? [Response(url, false)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is

Comment: `Response.End()` always raises an exception so that it can, well, end things...