# How to fix 'Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack' error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling a method which calls an another method asynchronously(using delegates) ..But its not working as expected ..throws this

```
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a 
native frame is on top of the call stack'` exception..
```

Please help guys

Below is the method which I am calling

```
public bool ProcessInvoices(string printGroupId, bool isControlNum)
{
    //Create delegate for asynchronous operation
    ProcessInvoicesDelegate _processInvoicesDelegate = new ProcessInvoicesDelegate(ProcessInvoicesFromCABSToExstream);
    IAsyncResult result = _processInvoicesDelegate.BeginInvoke(printGroupId, isControlNum, null, null);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What kind of application is this? is this Console application or Winform

Comment: Asp.net web application

Comment: Calling method defined in Business layer

Comment: Is the error appear only while debugging? are you using "Release" configuration" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is)

Comment: I am debugging it through unit test

Answer (score 2):

This only appears in a "watch"-window, right ? Some variables do not exist physically any more, if the "optimize code"-flag in the build properties is enabled. By default this is disabled for debug-build, and enabled for release build, but it can be modified.

Comment: Yes.So what would be the solution?

Comment: uncheck the "optimize code" checkbox. That's what the message sais: It cannot be done, cause you have optimization enabled. So turn it off.

Comment: Cannot find optimization option.I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: In each project, first entry in Solution explorer is "Properties", (Since 2001). Click on that, Than on the "Build" page. And than it's about the 4th checkbox.